# Extract wordlist from wordweb lst files

Tags: dictionary, nlp

**Hi.. I am working on a natural language processing project (It will be on JAVA)... A paragraph of text goes in and it (will) extracts information from the paragraph and add it to its database... Like give it text of wikipedia and it will update its database...
First of all I have to identify verbs, nouns, adjectives, etc(all the facts known in advance) from the paragraph..**

It can be done using a dictionary database from which I can query if a word is Verb, Noun, Adjective or something else...

**But the problem is I can't find a dictionary database to download...
Or is there any other way I can do this... Please tell me if I am not clear...!!**

Comment: Read more about NLP, Part-of-Speech Tagging, word classification. And maybe you will find the answers you need.

Comment: Okay... I'll study those..Thanks 2er0.. !!